# Are there any disadvantages of using off-perk weapons?

Tags: killing-floor-2

There's two off perk weapons in the game so far, the katana and the flamethrower. I'm wondering if there's a negative benefit to having the two. Does it affect the way I play any class? Is there any downside to using them?

Comment: Flamethrower and Katana are off perk?  **Why does KF2 not have Firebug and Brawler as Perks any more!!!**

Comment: @powerlord It's going to be implemented in the future, but the current perks are only Commando, Support Spec, Med, and Berz

Comment: I haven't played the game so someone correct me if I'm wrong, but don't you reload perk guns faster if you are in that perk and high enough level?

Comment: I haven't played the game, but I'm pretty sure there are no disadvantages until the perks for them are added. Of course you don't get to use the perks that improve your other weapons, but if you're out of ammo anyway I think there's nothing wrong with switching to off-perk weapons.

Comment: The only negatives I am aware of are the lack of levelling classes that aren't in game (yet) and burn damage from enemies when you're not the Firebug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off-perk weapons do not give you class exp. This means that as a Berzerker, you will not gain exp for the class with the Katana, which is an off-perk weapon (intended for the Martial Artist, who is not out yet).

However, off-perk weapons do technically have some use for the Demolitionist class.  At rank 20 there is a choice between two perks, On-Perk and Off-Perk, the latter which adds bonus damage when using off-perk weapons.

Comment: The katana is now a beserker class weapon btw

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the only disadvantage of using the katana and flamethrower is that you don't get a class boost of any kind. I'm certain some kind of melee class will be added in the future to cover the katana though.

Other than this, they do have their uses. The katana, just like in KF1, is the best melee weapon due to its long range and quickness. As for the flamethrower, it obviously does something other weapons don't do: throw flames — great for lighting enemies on fire from a distance.